# How to observe data from live data android on Three different Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have my Activity `MainActivity.kt` .

And and one ViewModel `MainActivityViewModel.kt`

And I want to observe my live data to my 3 different fragments.

```
class MainActivity{
      
      lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
      ...

     mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}

class MainFragmentOne{
      
      lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
      ...

     mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

But my observer only work on activity not on the fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there you are doing everything greate except one thing you should use `requireActivity()` instead on this in your fragment class.

Make sure your all fragment are attached to your `viewModel` holding Activity.

```
class MainActivity{

      lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
      ...

     mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}

class MainFragmentOne{

      lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
      ...

     mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

This will help you solve your issue.

For further detail [view](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) this.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewModelProviders.of has 2 different constructors:

```
of(Fragment fragment, ViewModelProvider.Factory factory)
```

> Creates a ViewModelProvider, which retains ViewModels while a scope of
>   given fragment is alive.

```
of(FragmentActivity activity, ViewModelProvider.Factory factory)
```

> Creates a ViewModelProvider, which retains ViewModels while a scope of
>   given Activity is alive.

Basically when you used **this** as the first parameter in your activity, you passed the context of the activity and created a viewmodel that will be alive in the scope of the activity, however your second **this** is the context to your fragment, meaning that the second ViewModel will be alive as long as your fragment is alive (only one fragment).

What instead you should be doing in your fragment is using the context of the activity, since activity is always alive when fragments are attached and swapped. You should change your fragments to:

```
class MainFragmentOne{

      lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel
      ...

     mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

or you can use the requireActivity() method that was the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need three things. An activity/fragment that will post the value to the `ViewModel`, a `ViewModel`, and an activity/fragment that will retrieve the data from the `ViewModel`. Lets say your data is stored in an `ArrayList`, and you want to update and retrieve it from different fragments.
First, we have to implement a `ViewModel`. It contains the data you want to share between your activities/fragments. You declare the `MutableLiveData` as an `ArrayList` then initialize it.

```
class testviewmodel : ViewModel() {
    val list: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    init {
        list.value = arrayListOf()
    }
}
```

Our next step is to access and update the `ArrayList` using your activity:

```
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(testviewmodel::class.java)
    // update the array in Viewmodel
    viewmodel.list.postValue(yourarray)
```

If you are using a `Fragment` to update it, use this:

```
    activity?.let {
        val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(testviewmodel::class.java)
         // update the array in Viewmodel
        viewmodel.list.postValue(yourarray)
    }
```

Finally, to retrieve the data from the `ViewModel` in a fragment, put this inside your `onViewCreated`:

```
activity?.let {
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(Dbviewmodel::class.java)
    observeInput(viewmodel)
}
```

Put this outside of your `onViewCreated`:

```
private fun observeInput(viewmodel: testviewmodel ) {

    viewmodel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            if (it.size > 5) {
                pos = it[5]
//grab it
                Toast.makeText(context,pos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//display grabbed data
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Take a look at this [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for more information about `ViewModels`
Good Luck! I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the fragment 'this' instance, and not the activity.

Replace

```
mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

With

```
activity?.let { mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it, viewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java) }
```